# Flask Render Template from Imported Module

Tags: python, templates, flask

Say I have a route in Flask like this:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

but I want to call a function in an imported module to render the template instead, so I do:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    models.goto_homepage()
```

and in `models.py` I have

```
def goto_homepage():
    return render_template("index.html")
```

What conceptual error am I making?

The `"/"` view doesn't return a valid template, but the function it calls does...

Is there a way to have a view call a function from an imported module and have that function render the desired template?

Comment: Is your model.goto_homepage alive in the scope of your route function? Check it by using a simplier function like print('something') to see if it's alive. Act accoridingly to the result of this check

Answer (score 2):

Your `def index()` function needs a return value.
You are just executing the function. Something like this should work:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
     return models.goto_homepage()
```